# SEDE login authentication

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, login, authentication

I have the impression that SE's login is *universal*.  Once logged into any one of the sites on the SE network, one can enter other sites *without* further login.  For example, I'm logged into Math.SE, so I'm also logged into Stat.SE.

SEDE's domain name also contains "stackexchange.com".  What's the reason for providing the SE account password *once again* for SEDE login after being logged into other SE sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer is...](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)

> ...an open source tool for running arbitrary queries against public data from the Stack Exchange network. Features include collaborative query editing for all graduated and public beta Stack Exchange sites.

While it's *hosted* by Stack Exchange, it'll never be able to access the 'regular' Stack Exchange databases with account information; the credentials for that simply can't be made public. So you'll have to manually allow SEDE to login with your Stack Exchange account.

Comment: I'm wondering what would happen if we add an Stack API application where we use the oAuth authentication flow to login.